# Using Generalized Linear Mixed-Effects Models with percentage value as dependent variable

Tags: mixed-model, percentage

```
I have two studies:
STUDY1:
Independent variables: 
 1. between-subject factor ABILITY (typical, deficit) 
 2. within-subject categorical variable TEST_LANGUAGE (lang1, lang2) 
 3. within-subject categorical variable YEAR (year1, year2).
Dependent variable:
 1. VSCORE, a percentage value, in effect a continuous variable with min=0.0 max=100.0

STUDY2:
Independent variables: 
 1. between-subject a percentage value, in effect a continuous variable with min=20.0 max=100.0 
 2. within-subject categorical variable TEST_LANGUAGE (lang1, lang2) 
 3. within-subject categorical variable YEAR (year1, year2).
Dependent variable:
 1. VSCORE, a percentage value, in effect a continuous variable with min=0.0 max=100.0

 Should I be running generalized linear mixed-effect models with family=binomial, link=logit? I am not sure if this is the right test.
I am using R.
```

Comment: In addition to Dimitri's suggestion you can check the R packages [`glmmTMB`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/) and [`glmmADMB`](http://glmmadmb.r-forge.r-project.org/). The package [`mgcv`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/) also allows for a beta response.

Answer (score 8):

You could consider a Beta mixed effects model that can be fitted under maximum likelihood in R by package [GLMMadaptive](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/). For more info, check the vignette: https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Custom_Models.html#beta-mixed-effects-model